# JavaScript: why array.push() appends two objects instead of one

Tags: javascript

I am quite new to JS and there is a problem with my code that I really don't understand: I try to append a text-value pair to an array and basically it works, but instead of appending a single pair, it appends two pairs. Below is the code snippet and the problem is in the latter if-statement. I have added comments on to the snippet to explain what I am doing.

```
 players.addResult = function(result){

 //result-argument contains results of games, like: Object {0: "4-2", 1: "5-3", 2: "7-1"}


    var playerList = [];        
    var standingArray = [];

    resultLen = Object.keys(result).length;

    //loop iterates thru results by index
    for (var x=0; x < resultLen; x++) {
        var newResult = result[x];
        newResult = newResult.split("-");

        if (newResult[0] > newResult[1]) {

            //the next line retrieves the name of a winning player from another array
            playerVal = players.pairs[x].player1;
            playerVal = playerVal.text;
            console.log(playerVal); //Output of this: Bill
            value = playerList.indexOf(playerVal); // Checks if the player already exists on the standings, returns -1 if false.

            if (value === -1) {

          /*if the player gets his first points, his name and earned
          points are added on to the standingArray. And the next line of code is the
          interesting one, because I am expecting to have an array with
          index, name of the winner and points. Like this: 
          Object 0 name:"Bill" points:2. But  instead of that, there are two                 
          objects on the array, one for both players: 
          [Object]
           0: Object
             name:  "Bill"
             points: 2
             __proto__: Object
           1: Object
             name: "Greg"
             points: 2
             __proto__: Object
          length: 2
          __proto__: Array[0]*/

                standingArray.push({name: playerVal, points: 2})

                playerList.push(playerVal); //this is for keeping on track that player is now on the standingArray

                console.log(playerVal);
                console.log(playerList);
                console.log(standingArray);
            }
            else {
                console.log("else");
            }               
        console.log(playerList);
        console.log(standingArray);
```

So the question is that how JS gets Greg's name - I have checked the playerVal-variable and it really contains only Bill's name. Any help is warmly welcome!

Comment: check `players.pairs` array, maybe Greg wins one game, and Bill wins another

Answer (score 0):

The output that appears in the console from `console.log` is alive. It reflects changes to the objects passed to `console.log` after the `console.log` call has occurred.

You might want to `JSON.stringify` before passing the object to `console.log` or make a copy of the Array:

```
console.log(playerList.slice());
console.log(standingArray.slice());
```